# vscode extension to format attribut name

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, format

I want to format attribut classe name with prefix automatically(company coding rules).

```
unsigned short  UIPortForMessages;
unsigned short  UIPortForGPSData;
bool            Thread;
unsigned short* IdOfFile;
```

Must became :

```
unsigned short  mUIPortForMessages;
unsigned short  mUIPortForGPSData;
bool            mThread;
unsigned short* mpIdOfFile;
```

I want m prefix for attributes and mp for pointer attributes.
Someone know how to do that automatically ?

Comment: Hungarian notation is not used anymore since that Hungarian guy left Microsoft

Comment: I know it but my company want to keep it...

Comment: if you have to use it why does `Thread` not have a type prefix, and why is prefix different for different `unsigned short` variables, an `int` is NOT a `short`, Use it everywhere correct or not use it at all.

Comment: cause my company coding rules are like this, just specify if  a number is unsigned, differentiate pointer and m for members. We don't use exactly Hungarian notation but some of rules

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own snippet to write code faster with that rule, if you want something to check existed code, I don't know